# How to sum a value in a JSONB array in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, psql, jsonb

Given the following data in the jsonb column `p06` in the table `ryzom_characters`:

```
        -[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    p06 | {
  "id": 675010,
  "cname": "Bob",
  "rpjobs": [
    {
      "progress": 25
    },
    {
      "progress": 13
    },
    {
      "progress": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

I am attempting to sum the value of `progress`. I have attempted the following:

```
    SELECT 
c.cname AS cname,
jsonb_array_elements(c.p06->'rpjobs')::jsonb->'progress' AS value 
FROM ryzom_characters c
Where cid = 675010
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Which correctly lists the values:

```
 cname  | value
--------+-------
 Savisi | 30
 Savisi | 25
 Savisi | 13
(3 rows)
```

But now I would like to sum these values, which could be null.

How do I correctly sum an object field within an array?

Here is the table structure:

```
                     Table "public.ryzom_characters"
    Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 cid           | bigint                 |           |          |
 cname         | character varying(255) |           | not null |
 p06           | jsonb                  |           |          |
 x01           | jsonb                  |           |          |
```

Comment: The data structure is not clear. Please, edit the question and add the table definition (\d ryzom_characters in psql).

Comment: @klin I added the table structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join in the from clause:

```
select cname, sum(coalesce(value, '0')::int) as value
from (
    select 
        p06->>'cname' as cname, 
        value->>'progress' as value
    from ryzom_characters
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(p06->'rpjobs')
    where cid = 675010
    ) s
group by cname
order by value desc 
limit 50;
```

You can use left join instead of cross join to protect the query against inconsistent data:

```
    left join jsonb_array_elements(p06->'rpjobs')
    on jsonb_typeof(p06->'rpjobs') = 'array'
    where p06->'rpjobs' <> 'null'
```

Comment: @kiln Is it possible to not restrict by cid with that query? Also cname is another column on the 'ryzom_characters' table, not a element in the p06 jsonb sorry will correct description.

Comment: Of course, you can skip the condition. Then you might want (or not) to add the column to select list and use it in `group by` clause in the outer query, depending on your expectations.

Comment: @kiln I am getting error: cannot extract elements from a scalar. When I removed the where clause?

Comment: Well, your data is not consistent, in some rows `'rpjobs'` is not an array.

Comment: @kiln it could be null in some rows. Is it possible to protect again this?

Comment: @kiln Still the same error: `cannot extract elements from a scalar`?

Comment: Just curious, what is more efficient: `select somecol, sum(value) from sometab cross join unnest(arraycol) as value group by somecol;` or `select somecol, (select sum(unnest) from unnest(arraycol)) from sometab;`? PS: I know that the result depends on uniqueness of `somecol`.

Comment: @Abelisto - I think the second option is a bit faster (not so much, maybe a few percent). The first query in my opinion is more convenient (flexible) when constructing queries. But it can be a matter of habit.

Answer (score 0):

The function `jsonb_array_elements()` is a set-returning function. You should therefore use it as a row source (in the `FROM` clause). After the call you have a table where every row contains an array element. From there on it is relatively easy.

```
SELECT cname, 
       sum(coalesce(r.prog->>'progress'::int, 0)) AS value  
FROM ryzom_characters c,
     jsonb_array_elements(c.p06->'rpjobs') r (prog)
WHERE c.cid = 675010
GROUP BY cname 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: This gives the error: `ERROR:  COALESCE types jsonb and integer cannot be matched`?

Comment: That was a type conversion error. See updated answer.

Comment: I get the error: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "progress"`?

Comment: That would indicate that `progress` has some data which is not an integer.