# Properly extracting JSON arrays from a JSONB field

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

From a table in PostgreSQL 10, I am trying to join all array elements in multiple children of the same `jsonb` field to their parent row somewhat like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798846/7376) or [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql). But I am making a mistake in the `JOIN` such that instead of getting the individual array elements, I get individual array elements wrapped inside a single-item array.

Here's the abbreviated table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.worker_customformstore (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('worker_customformstore_id_seq'::regclass),
    created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    store jsonb,
    schema_id integer NOT NULL,
    polymorphic_ctype_id integer,
    pdf_key character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_updated timestamp with time zone
)
```

and an example value for the `store` field:

```
'{"Subcontractor Use": {
        "labor": [
            {
                "note": null,
                "hours": {
                    "dt": null,
                    "ot": null,
                    "st": 1,
                    "pdt": null,
                    "pot": null
                },
                "employee": {
                    "id": 456,
                    "trade": "XXX",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "last_name": "Uknow",
                    "first_name": "Noone",
                    "company_supplied_id": "456"
                },
                "external subcontractor": false
            },
            {
                "note": null,
                "hours": {
                    "dt": null,
                    "ot": null,
                    "st": 8,
                    "pdt": null,
                    "pot": null
                },
                "employee": {
                    "id": 123,
                    "trade": "",
                    "member": null,
                    "is_active": true,
                    "last_name": "Guy",
                    "user_role": "WORKER",
                    "first_name": "Some",
                    "company_supplied_id": "123"
                },
                "external subcontractor": false
            }
        ],
        "Equipment": [
            {
                "note": null,
                "hours": {
                    "idle": null,
                    "over": null,
                    "running": 8
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "equipment": {
                    "id": 6243,
                    "status": "Rented",
                    "project": "8399",
                    "category": "XXXXX",
                    "caltrans_id": "00-20",
                    "description": "19",
                    "equipment_id": "Scissor",
                    "idle_time_price": 0,
                    "over_time_price": 0,
                    "running_time_price": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

My simplified query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
cufstore.id, 
CASE
    WHEN labor IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL THEN
    0
    WHEN (jsonb_array_elements(labor) -> 'hours' ->> 'st') = '' THEN
    0
    ELSE
    COALESCE((jsonb_array_elements(labor) -> 'hours' ->> 'st')::numeric, 0)
END
-- more stuff here ...
as total_hours,

CASE
    WHEN labor IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL THEN
    0
    ELSE
    COALESCE(jsonb_array_length(cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor'), 0)
END as total_workers,

labor, equipment

FROM public.worker_customformstore AS cufstore
...

LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT
        jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_strip_nulls(cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor'))
        WHERE cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' ->> 'labor' IS NOT NULL
    ) labor on true

LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT
        jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_strip_nulls(cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'Equipment'))
        WHERE cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' ->> 'Equipment' IS NOT NULL
    ) equipment on true
```

In addition to winding up with lots of redundant `jsonb_array_elements` calls, those prevent me from refactoring the repeated logic into a function because I get an error about about set-returning functions in a `COALESCE` in the function definition (though no complaint when it happens in the body of my query).

I think what I want is something more like:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL 
    jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_strip_nulls(cufstore.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor')) labor
    ON jsonb_typeof(labor) = 'array'
```

But trying that gives me `cannot extract elements from a scalar` when the data is `NULL` or does not look right.

I may be fundamentally misunderstanding what I can do but this is what the `equipment` column looks like:

```
("{""hours"": {""running"": 8}, ""quantity"": 1, . . .}")
```

and I'd like to be able to ask about `equipment -> 'hours' ->> 'running'` without having to wrap it in `jsonb_array_elements(equipment)`. Do I need to do that or am I accidentally adding the parentheses at the start and end of the column's value?

Comment: Best would be to create a fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/ would make it really easier to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear how elements of the two nested JSON arrays `"labor"` and `"Equipment"` are related. From your sample it seems like `"Equipment"` only has a single element and the array wrapper is just noise ...

It's unfortunate that there is also a nested key `"equipment"`, easy to confuse with the other.

I am also in the dark what the exact objective is.

Be that as it may, after removing a lot of noise and needless complication, this might be close to what you are after:

```
SELECT s.id
     , COALESCE((NULLIF(labor->'hours'->>'st', ''))::numeric, 0) AS total_hours
     , CASE WHEN labor IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE COALESCE(jsonb_array_length(s.store->'Subcontractor Use'->'labor'), 0)
       END AS total_workers
     , s.store #>> '{Subcontractor Use, Equipment, 0, hours, running}' AS equipment_hours
     , labor
FROM   worker_customformstore s
LEFT   JOIN jsonb_array_elements(s.store->'Subcontractor Use'->'labor') labor ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1e6ea4bdb16bdcb5b743a3fcc3449173)*

#### Notes

This lengthy expression:

```
CASE
    WHEN labor IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL THEN
    0
    WHEN (jsonb_array_elements(labor) -> 'hours' ->> 'st') = '' THEN
    0
    ELSE
    COALESCE((jsonb_array_elements(labor) -> 'hours' ->> 'st')::numeric, 0)
END
```

boils down to:

```
COALESCE((NULLIF(labor -> 'hours' ->> 'st', ''))::numeric, 0)
```

- Don't apply `jsonb_array_elements()` another time, that's already done in the lateral subquery.
- `labor IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL` is the same as `labor IS NULL`, but we don't need either as the later `COALESCE` does it anyway.
- Using `NULLIF` we don't need `CASE` with another branch at all.

***Assuming*** there is only a single element in the nested JSON array `"Equipment"`, we can access `equipment_hours` directly with 
`s.store #>> '{Subcontractor Use, Equipment, 0, hours, running}'`. If the assumption does not hold, you'll have to do more (and explain more).

---

#### Addressing [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756360/properly-extracting-json-arrays-from-postgresql-10-jsonb-fields/56809504#comment100262900_56809504)

**If** `store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor'` is not a nested JSON array but, for example, a scalar instead, you get an error like you commented:

> ```
> ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=953aba6ea99e77dedba0873eca975104)*

You might avoid the exception with a nested `CASE` like:

```
...
LEFT   JOIN jsonb_array_elements(
          CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(s.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor') = 'array'
               THEN              s.store -> 'Subcontractor Use' -> 'labor'
          END) labor ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b1be6a79ececa239ec1a1d053942a206)*

You may want to do more to return alternative values for the case ...

Comment: Sorry, yes: labor, equipment and material are all the same thing, arrays of data at the same level. And agreed on the redundant nested keys. Thanks, I will test this next week and see if it matches. The simplified expression is a help as well; I think I'd put that together before discovering `jsonb_strip_nulls`.

Comment: This simplified approach is great and it works well when the data is clean. If I run this across the whole data set though, I get `ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar`. This is when I simplify things down to just querying for hours and do the one join like you showed for `labor`. The fact `labor` may not exist or the parent itself may not exist in the JSON is why I had that torturous `CASE` statement. Is there a way to handle this in the `JOIN`/ `WHERE`? Thanks no matter what, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tom: I added some more above to address your exception.